# Returning a value from a void method via other non void method

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a Void method called A, and a method that returns a Object from A called C.

The method A is the response of the call by a method called B that only sends a request for the method A to respond, and I want to send the response, wait for it and then return it on the same method (Method C).

The method A is a method from the superclass so I cant modify it.
The method is the method of a API, I call it providing the arguments I want and then the method A is going to do a response with that arguments.

I also want to be thread-safe because the response needs to be exact, otherwise the program will fail.

Method A's:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(Object response) {
    //The args of the method is what I want to return in method C.
}
```

Method B's:

```
requestResponse(data);
```

Method C's:

```
public Object sendMessage(byte[] data) {
    requestResponse(data);
    return /*  THE RESPONSE FROM METHOD A */; 
}
```

I have tried to do something in method A like:

```
this.response = response;
```

And in method C:

```
return this.response;
```

But I dont think this is secure and practical.
I have also thought about making a new instance every request, but that can take much memory and time.
The method C cant take the time it want to return the response.
Some people told me to use Future<> or other classes, but I'm really confused and I dont know what to do.
I can have as much instances to send the request I want, but I can only have one class that returns the response, so only one inhertired method that provides the response for the other classes that request the response.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't return anything from a void method. That's what void means.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean...

Comment: Please edit your question so that it has a more realistic title. Something like 'Returning a value via callbacks' should help to get useful answers.

Comment: Also, I recommend you take one step at a time. First solve how to get the response with the methods and constraints you have. Then, see how you could make everything asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to do something in method A like `this.response = response` and in method C: `return this.response` but I dont think this is secure and practical.

No, it isn't, because it would not be thread safe. There is a race condition where method C could return the `response` that was assigned when processing the response from an unrelated request made by another thread.

> I have also thought about making a new instance every request, but that can take much memory and time.

This approach will avoid the race condition. Depending on the cost of object instantiation and the number of concurrent requests that you expect, maybe it is the correct approach. After you are done with an object, its memory will be reclaimed by the garbage collector. Of course, if each object allocates 10MB and you have 1000 concurrent requests, that would not work.

If the parent class is thread safe (i.e. it can handle several request at the same timen, which should be explained in the API documentation), and you need to use the same instance for every request, you could associate the response with the calling thread, by using a [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) (assuming that `onMessageReceived` is called by the same thread that invoked `sendMessage`):

```
private ThreadLocal<Object> responses;

public void onMessageReceived(Object response) {
   response.set(response);
} 

public Object sendMessage(byte[] data) {
   requestResponse(data);
   Object response = responses.get();
   responses.remove();
   return response;
}
```

Comment: ThreadLocal seems to be what I need, but I have to say that the method A  needs to be registered on a list inside the API, so it will send and recieve data correctly, so I cant keep registering and unregistering a instance of that class because in this api that needs to be on the main class and a lot of workaround. Thanks for your helpful answer, hope it goes well.